# Is there a wildcard/catchall filter hook?

Tags: filters, options

I would like to filter all the options values, but the option filters are option specific. 
Is there a way I could do something like

```
add_filter('pre_option_*', 'my_check');
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried the same thing and was able to hook into the `pre_option_` filter by using `all` as filter.

```
add_filter('all', 'pre_option_',1,3);

function pre_option_($actionHook,$bool=false,$option_name)
{
    if(strpos($actionHook,'pre_option_') === FALSE){
        return $bool;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use `wp_load_alloptions()` and add a filter for each:

```
foreach ( array_keys( wp_load_alloptions() ) as $option ) {
    add_filter( 'pre_option_' . $option, function ( $pre ) use ( $option ) {
        // blah
        return $pre;
    } );
}
```

Comment: even tough this is actually an answer it would mean to add like 200+ filters which does not seem like a good idea to me

Comment: No, it probably isn't. Why do you want to pre-filter all the options?

Comment: so that I can have a single configuration for all the plugins I use in a multisite setup without having to replicate all the options in all the _options tables, if all the plugins provided support for multisite with `get_site_option` it would have been simple but not everyone  use it. Of course if this was possible I would trim out wordpress core options for each subsite which are ~100, but wordpress does not provide a general hook when getting the options

Comment: Oh that's interesting - if you add that info to your question you may get better responses...

Comment: not all options are loaded from DB at that time, only the autoloading one do, and obviously you miss the options being created at the specific session